# CR: Show if value is not in chosen elements

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a list of invoices, and I need to verify if they are in our system or not.

What I need to show is:

```
INVOICE # 75263012--> ok
INVOICE # 75263404--> missing
INVOICE # 75261778--> ok
```

Of course, if I try to use the select it will show only values that ARE there, not those that aren't there.

```
    {Invoices.InvNumber} in 
    ["75263012",
    "75263404",
    "75261778"]
```

Will obviously get what is in there. How can I get CR to let me know if for example the third value is not in the pulled list?
Thanks!

Comment: is there any table in database where you have all invoices numbers? or irrespective of invoice numbers in database you need the data in database

Comment: They're not in any table unfortunately, they're on an Excel file. That's why I used {Invoices.InvNumber} in 
    ["75263012",
    "75263404",
    "75261778"]

Comment: Is it possible to create one more sheet with full data?

Comment: yes i can have a list of all the invoices needed

Comment: In that case create one more sheet with full data and add both sheets and link left join to full data sheet and required data sheet and run the report

Answer (score 1):

Create a left join from your table that contains all invoices to the table that contains some of the data

Then create a formula that returns "missing" if value from second table is null else "ok"